# xcode simulator crash with some dyld error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-catalina

I can run my app on device but when I run it on simulator, I got an error, how can I run it on a simulator?
xcode version: 12.1
simulator version: 14.1
I can't lunch the simulator now

```
Process:               SpringBoard [8490]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:            SpringBoard
Version:               1.0 (50)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [8020]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [784]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-11-04 18:33:21.811 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4B907FF2-14B6-5989-E5EB-360FD491CCA0


Time Awake Since Boot: 5400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x5] Code Signature

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/19H2/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-1.18A8394
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlatform.framework/MediaPlatform
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaLibraryCore.framework/MediaLibraryCore
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlatform.framework/MediaPlatform: code signature invalid for '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlatform.framework/MediaPlatform'

Binary Images:
       0x10286f000 -        0x102875fff  com.apple.springboard (1.0 - 50) <5E08B57A-06BC-3482-9CD7-3E821C3DBD85> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
```

Comment: That's really bizarre, the error says "code signature invalid". I wonder if somehow your copy of Xcode is corrupted? Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: I copy the MediaPlatform library files from my colleague, it's work.